# Guaranteed no border around Windows file thumbnails

Tags: windows, thumbnails

I'm trying to get a thumbnail image from a file as large as possible up to 256x256, where I'm guaranteed not to have the ugly border around it.

In lieu of being able to do that, I could detect the border and remove it manually, but that's an ugly way to do things, and doesn't port well to different Windows versions.

I'm currently grabbing the thumbnail with `IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage`.

As far as I can tell there's no way to find out whether Windows found it necessary to put a border around an icon that wasn't big enough. I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me that I'm wrong and let me know how to do it the right way.

Comment: Ask for a small SIZE and use the SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK flag.  And stretch the image yourself as needed.

Comment: I want the largest size possible. How would I find the largest size that still is borderless?